# MSDN Entity Framework Code First Tutorial: SQL Error

Tags: c#, entity-framework, ef-code-first, sqlexception

I am going through [this tutorial on MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/data/jj193542).
This is all the code in the very first part of the tutorial.

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Data.Entity;

namespace CodeFirstNewDatabaseSample
{
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        using (var db = new BloggingContext())
        {
            // Create and save a new Blog 
            Console.Write("Enter a name for a new Blog: ");
            var name = Console.ReadLine();

            var blog = new Blog { Name = name };
            db.Blogs.Add(blog);
            db.SaveChanges();

            // Display all Blogs from the database 
            var query = from b in db.Blogs
                        orderby b.Name
                        select b;

            Console.WriteLine("All blogs in the database:");
            foreach (var item in query)
            {
                Console.WriteLine(item.Name);
            }

            Console.WriteLine("Press any key to exit...");
            Console.ReadKey();
        }
    }
}

public class Blog
{
    public int BlogId { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }

    public virtual List<Post> Posts { get; set; }
}

public class Post
{
    public int PostId { get; set; }
    public string Title { get; set; }
    public string Content { get; set; }

    public int BlogId { get; set; }
    public virtual Blog Blog { get; set; }
}

public class BloggingContext : DbContext
{
    public DbSet<Blog> Blogs { get; set; }
    public DbSet<Post> Posts { get; set; }
}
}
```

Compiling this, according to the tutorial should give me this:

Enter a name for a new Blog: ADO.NET Blog
All blogs in the database: 
ADO.NET Blog 
Press any key to exit...

But instead I get an unhandled SqlException: 
CREATE DATABASE permission denied in database 'master'.

Is the tutorial missing crucial information or is there something wrong with my setup?

EDIT: So my colleague said I was missing connectionStrings in my app.config.

after adding:

```
<connectionStrings>
    <add name="blogContext" connectionString="Server=(localdb)\v11.0;Integrated Security=true;" providerName="System.Data.SqlClient"/> 
</connectionStrings>
```

The console application ran, and I was able to see multiple blog entries when running the program again. But the next step in the tutorial where it says to connect through server explorer, neither ((localdb)\v11.0) or (.\SQLEXPRESS) appear as options.

Comment: It looks like your DBContext has an issue.  I don't think it should be trying to go to your 'master' database.  What does your root configuration file look like?

Comment: Seems like the process trying to create the database doesn't have proper permissions to create a database on your sql server instance. You need to add database create permissions to the account that is trying to create the database.

Comment: did you successfully create the data base and connection? if yes then your model is something different than your data base design, check relations in both model and SQL server.

Comment: go to SQL server and create a blank database to let entity framework create the tables for you, it seems that it's mostly because of permission issues.